# R subsetting an integer sequence

Tags: r, logical-operators

I have an integer sequence y<-1:6 and a integer object f<-5
Now if I applying subsetting to this sequence as

```
y[f=5] returns 5
y[f<3] returns numeric(0)
y[f>3] returns 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Please help me in understanding the expression evaluation inside [].

Comment: It's called ***logical indexing***. If f was a vector, `f>3` would generate a logical vector of TRUE or FALSE elements, which can then be used to index into y. But in your case `f>3` is a simple scalar and thus generates one logical value (TRUE), which is then used to index into y with recycling... i.e. equivalent to an index of all-TRUE values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The three statements inside the brackets do fundamentally different things:

1. The first line *assigns* `5` to `f`, and then uses it to subset `y`.<sup>1</sup>
2. The second and third line *compare* `f` to `3` (either less than or greater than), and use the result of the comparison (`FALSE` in the first case, `TRUE` in the second case) to subset `y`.

   Now, subsetting using a logical values simply selects all values inside `y` for which the respective given index is `TRUE`. Since you’ve given only one logical index, but `y` contains six values, the logical index is *recycled* – i.e. `FALSE` is turned into `rep(FALSE, length(y))` (and the same for `TRUE`). Hence the respective results.

<sup>1</sup> It’s actually slightly more complicated than that, because assignment using `=` inside a function call’s argument list doesn’t assign to a variable, it assigns to the argument of the same name:

```
test = function (a) a
test(1) # returns 1
test(a = 1) # also returns 1
test(b = 1) # error: unused argument (b = 1)
```

And subsetting (`y[f]`) is simply a function call in R. It’s calling a function called `[`, and is thus equivalent to

```
`[`(y, f)
```

Try it yourself! The backticks around `[` are necessary because ordinarily, `[` wouldn’t be a valid function name. In order to use it like a regular function name, R requires special characters to be put between backticks.

So why doesn’t `y[f = 5]` give an error, since there is no argument called `f` for the `[]` function call? The reason is that `[` is a *primitive* rather than a normal R function call, and primitives ignore argument names completely.

Assignment using `<-` works differently, it always assigns to a new variable in the current scope, even if it’s used in a function call:

```
y[f <- 1] # returns the first element of y
f # is now 1, not 5!
```

Comment: And, point 1 means that you can assign multiple variables to the same value in one line, e.g. `y1 <- y2 <- y3 <- 5`

Answer (score 1):

It's called ***logical indexing***.

If f was a vector, `f>3` would generate a logical vector of TRUE or FALSE elements, which can then be used to index into y.

But in your case `f>3` is a simple scalar and thus generates one logical value (TRUE), which is then used to index into y with recycling... i.e. equivalent to an index of all-TRUE values.